# To display error msg with label in required field validator

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i have a label,textbox,required field validator.Now my aim is if a user have  not type a value in a textbox it should display a error msg with label text.(ie)if a label text is employee name.the error msg should display please enter employee name.Pls help me to do this.

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" width="200Px"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" width="200Px" onfocus="But1()"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtreq" ControlToValidate="txtField" runat="server"   ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

codebebind:

```
 txtreq.Text = lblText.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code should be something like:

```
Page.Validate();
if (!Page.IsValid)
{
     //show a message or throw an exception
}
```

and add the following property to RequiredFieldValidator

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ErrorMessage="please enter employee name"
```

Comment: I want the error msg with label.Label can have any text.

Comment: You can add that at the place of //show a message or throw an exception , if this is not what you want could you please give more clarification whether you need client side or server side...

Comment: How can i add a text with label.I got the label value. txtreq.Text = lblText.Text;i want pls fill this+label value.

Comment: I think I got your point, no need to do that since every textbox has its separate RequiredFieldValidator, so you will have for example for employeeFirstNameTEXT one RequiredFieldValidator and For EmployeeLastName another RequiredFieldValidator..

Comment: i got the right value by  txtreq.Text =  "Please fill this field" + lblText.Text ;  thanks for help